# Window 7 Event Log Freezing. How to Fix?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, event-log

When you open the event log, it freeze for several seconds. and a prompt comes out say it's not responding. but if you ignore it and wait for several seconds, it will resume normal. And you will found the following entry in the event log

[image: Event Log Freeze]

The size of eventlog isn't very large and the computer have quite enough amount of memory.
[image: Event Log Size]

some may be relayed hints:
[image: Event 4625]

[image: Event 108]

It's a HP machine with HP Quick Web, so i guess the DvmMDES is not malware

[image: HP Quick Web]

Comment: The eventlog service itself is hanged. seems like a contention, but the large amount of log it not very large in my opinion.

Comment: Did you browse through the logs to see if there were an errors?

Comment: There are, but not at the moment, at least 4-6 hours away, for which i think is non-related.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but how old is the installation of W7? From your pictures it looks like you've tweaked/skinned it etc. I wonder if you've made X amount of changes then one of these is causing a conflict or similar.

Comment: it's around 3.5 years, work in good conditions.

Comment: What is with that edit history

Answer (score 1):

There is a [hot fix for this which may help](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2499016) your issue. Depends on your Windows Updates.

I would also run the following from the command prompt

> SFC /SCANNOW

Lastly, a [clean boot may help](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135). If it does then you can disable them on start up one at a time until you find the culprit (only do this if you know what you're doing).